# Set negative leading for a block of text (with a specific font) using lualatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, typography, line-spacing

I'm typesetting a block of text within the `quote` environment which should represent an handwritten letter.

I'm using lualatex and I was given a specific font to work with for this special part of the text. Now, using fontspec, I defined an environment to achieve what is needed:

```
\newfontfamily\finob{TheActualFont}[%
Ligatures={TeX,Historic},
Variant=3]
\newenvironment{itaquote}{%
\begin{quote}\finob}
{%
\end{quote}
}
```

The problem is that the leading should be reduced, possible set to be negative in this environment, because it does not look that good. How can it be done?
Thanks

Comment: How is the leading set elsewhere in the document? E.g., are you using the `setspace` package? Please advise.

Comment: No, the rest of the book is typeset with standard leading and a different font (caslon pro, if I'm not mistaken). No `setspace`  package, but if it's necessary to use that or another one… please do answer!

Comment: `\begin{quote}\linespread{0.9}\finob}` ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried them, and I think David's answer is working the best since I don't have to reset it afterwards, nor I have to load any extra packages. I will have to print to see if it's actually as good as I need it but with linespread set to 0.5 I think it's ok. Thanks. Do you have any more informations to (maybe) do some tweaks in the future? If this is the case please: answer so that I can mark this as properly answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use

```
 ...\begin{quote}\linespread{0.9}\finob} ...
```

to reduce the baseline spacing to 90% of its previous value within the environment, although if you reduce it too much (to less than the actual space taken by the characters in the font) then TeX will not preserve equal spacing, and lines with descenders or capitals or accented letters etc will take more vertical space that ones without, which usually looks poor.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{3cm}

\begin{document}

\linespread{.2}\selectfont

One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.
One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.
One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.
One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.
One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.
One two thee four five six Seven eight nine ten.

\end{document}
```